# Loading MVC Content Inside Web Forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Using iframes for content in existing web application loading asp.net web forms pages,
We would like to load the content from MVC views using jquery load().
The 2 reasons are:

1. Faster load time - web forms are heavy.
2. Would like to learn MVC.

Is it possible?
Is it a good practive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I think Good practice or not is a subjective question. If you have a huge web forms application, complete rewrite is out of budget, time and skills available and for some ease you want to add more features using MVC or WebApi (read about it, you might consider using it instead), it's completely ok. Depends on your scenario. Here are some good read about it:

[Mixing webforms and MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/)

[Integrating WebForms with MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)